# Random Spaces in PHP Variable

Tags: php, html, css, email, html-email

I am using the following PHP code to send e-mail when the users submits a form.

```
$to = 'mail@example.com';
$subject = 'Thank you for your mail ' . $mailRefrence . ' - www.example.com';
$headers = "From: " . 'info@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'> <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;.......";
$message .= $mailReference;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Please note that the HTML-code inside the $message-variable is much longer, I've just removed it due to it is way to long to be pasted here.

However, when the mail is sent to the user, there is random spaces in the text. Sometimes the spaces appear in the text, and sometimes in the code which often ruins the whole design of the mail.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to solve it?

EDIT:

I am using ZURB template for the HTML mail.

The source code is available here: http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-email-templates/basic.html

Comment: Put the "spaced" result. Otherwise we can't see what happens

Comment: Are you perhaps using enters and tabs in the html for readability?

Comment: Try use trim() function.
trim($message),and then use it.
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Comment: If the random spacing appears in the HTML mail, then the HTML mail would likely be most relevant.

Comment: Trim() function didn't work sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
$message = <<< EOD

your message content will be here ...it will show as you send either it is space or new line doesn't effect.

EOD;
```

Comment: This is called [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in PHP and is the proper way to assign multi-line preformatted text to a variable.